# Using case_when for nested ifelse statements

Tags: dplyr, case

I have data that looks like this sample:

```
 A1<-seq(3,5); A2<-seq(1,5); A3<-seq(2,8)
length(A1)<-7; length(A2)<-7; length(A3)<-7
adf <-as.data.frame(cbind(A1,A2,A3))

 A1 A2 A3
1  3  1  2
2  4  2  3
3  5  3  4
4 NA  4  5
5 NA  5  6
6 NA NA  7
7 NA NA  8
```

I would like to create a new variable that pulls from A1, unless it is a missing value, in which case it pulls from A2, unless there is also a missing value, in which case it pulls from A3. This is what I have tried:

```
 adf %>% 
mutate(
B = case_when(
      !is.na(A1) ~ A1, 
      is.na(A1) ~ A2, 
      (is.na(A1) & is.na(A2) & !is.na(A3)) ~ A3
    )
  )

  A1 A2 A3  B
1  3  1  2  3
2  4  2  3  4
3  5  3  4  5
4 NA  4  5  4
5 NA  5  6  5
6 NA NA  7 NA
7 NA NA  8 NA
```

This works for the most part but as you can see, in cases where both A1 and A2 are missing, but A3 is not, it return NAs instead of A3. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `coalesce` function handles just this use case. You can do:

```
adf %>% mutate(B=coalesce(A1, A2, A3))
```

giving:

```
  A1 A2 A3 B
1  3  1  2 3
2  4  2  3 4
3  5  3  4 5
4 NA  4  5 4
5 NA  5  6 5
6 NA NA  7 7
7 NA NA  8 8
```

Comment: Thank you. I will use this instead. Out of curiosity, any idea what was going wrong with my use of case_when?

Comment: The terms in the case_when are checked in order, and the `is.na(A1) ~ A2` term applies whenever A1 is NA - even if A2 is also NA. It would work if you reordered the terms (put the `... ~A2` term last).